# How do i only set Z axis on Vector

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create a Vector in geometry nodes that only sets the Z axis from a Number input.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using *Combine XYZ* node:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked